# Python Jabber/XMPP client library for Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, xmpp

I am looking for a Python library for writing Jabber/XMPP clients using the Twisted framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wokkel](http://wokkel.ik.nu/) is your best bet.  It's an enhancement on the core Twisted Words functionality built into Twisted.  It has several major users, include the guys behind [Stanziq/Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/).

Answer (score 2):

[Twisted Words](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords)