# Read string without parsing in Python xml.dom

Tags: python, xml, dom, xmpp, w3c

As you probably know, Pythons xml.dom readString() throws an exception, if there is anything wrong with the xml code.

I am currently writing a simple xmpp chat server, and as you probably also know, one of the first client request message does not close the stream:stream tag, until it does not get a reply.

Is there any way to use pythons xml.dom without "parsing" the xmlcode or should I write my own xml parser?

Answer (score 2):

DOM parsers always need to read the entire XML file. You want a [SAX parser](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're not using an already established XMPP library like [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/)? ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248587/python-jabber-xmpp-client-library-for-twisted))

Comment: why does apple program mac os instead of using windows?
I just want to earn practice and have sum fun...

Answer (score 0):

The parser that is likely to give you the best experience is [xml.parsers.expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html).  In your `StartElementHandler` create a DOM element, and add it to the current element as a child, then set the current element to the new element.  In your `EndElementHandler`, pop the current element to that element's parent.  If the parent was `null`, you have a stanza.  Do careful testing of namespaces; you're liable to get the attributes wrong the first time.